# Exclude rewrite url for specific file

Tags: angular, .htaccess

I have an Angular website and use the following .htaccess file, to rewrite url and use `index.html`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I need to exclude requests to `static.php`, tried many solutions, but didn't work, like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I exclude requests to https://example.com/static.php from being rewrite or redirected

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```